# What's that |t - filter for?

Tags: string, localization

I found this part of code in the documentation

```
{% set title = "Cocktail Recipes"|t %}
```

What does `|t` mean there?

Comment: And I was actually looking for the syntax on how to translate something in a set statement ;) glad I found this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the short syntax for the [translate filter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#translate-or-t). Set up a translation file as described in [the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations) and the string you apply that filter to is translated according to it.